# Get the value from edittext,save it in listview

Tags: android

How do I get the value from `EditText` and save it in `ListView` of another `Activity`. Each time I give the value in `EditText` it should be saved permanently in the `ListView` one after the other. Here is my code.

MainActivity where I am retrieving edittext values into listview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar bar=getActionBar();
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    String item=getIntent().getStringExtra("location");
    adapter.add(item);
```

Comment: Add it to `list` before setting your `Adapter`.

Comment: alternately call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after each addition;

Comment: That is fine what ever the value I give in edittext is displayed on listview, but my question is if I enter "script 1" that should be saved again if I enter "script 2" that should also be saved in listview after script 1 .. please tell me how to add the values to listview one after the other...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

every time you add a value in EditText along with adding it to list you also need to save it somewhere else(eg.in shared preferences) so that values don't get lost while this activity reinitilizes coz that will reinitilize the list adapter as well. If not compulsary why don't you add values to list in same activity?